# Why doesn't my program speed up after using reserve?

Tags: c++, string

I wrote two functions. In the second one I used "reserve" so that there is no memory reallocation, but unfortunately the second function is not faster than the first. I wrote out string addresses and in the first function there is a reallocation several times and yet both functions perform at the same time.

I think it should be much faster, am I wrong?

```
    string commpres2(string str)
    {
        string strOut;
        int count = 0;
        //int adress = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        {
            ++count;
            if (i < str.length() - 1)
            {
                if (str[i + 1] != str[i])
                {
                    strOut += str[i];
                    strOut += to_string(count);
                    /*if (adress != (int)&strOut[0])
                    {
                        adress = (int)&strOut[0];
                        cout << adress << endl;
                    }*/
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strOut += str[i] + to_string(count);
            }
        }
        return strOut.length() < str.length() ? strOut : str;
    }

    string commpres3(string str)
    {
        string strOut;
        strOut.reserve(7000000);
        int count = 0;
        //int adress = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        {
            ++count;
            if (i < str.length() - 1)
            {
                if (str[i + 1] != str[i])
                {
                    strOut += str[i];
                    strOut += to_string(count);
                    /*if (adress != (int)&strOut[0])
                    {
                        adress = (int)&strOut[0];
                        cout << adress << endl;
                    }*/
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strOut += str[i] + to_string(count);
            }
        }
        return strOut;
    }

    int main()
    {
        str = "aabcccccaaa";
        //str.size ~= 11000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            str += str;
        commpres2(str); //8 543ms
        commpres3(str); //8 534ms
    }
```

You are close to answering my question, but something is still missing. Below is the full version of my 'commpres3' function:

```
    string commpres3(string str)
    {
        int compressedLength = 0;
        int countConsecutive = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        {
            ++countConsecutive;
            if (i + 1 >= str.length() || str[i] != str[i + 1]) 
            {
                compressedLength += 1 + 
                    to_string(countConsecutive).length();
                countConsecutive = 0;
            }
        }
        if (compressedLength >= str.length())
            return str;
        string strOut;
        strOut.reserve(compressedLength);
        //strOut.reserve(7000000);
        int count = 0;
        //int adress = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        {
            ++count;
            if (i < str.length() - 1)
            {
                if (str[i + 1] != str[i])
                {
                    strOut += str[i];
                    strOut += to_string(count);
                    /*if (adress != (int)&strOut[0])
                    {
                        adress = (int)&strOut[0];
                        cout << adress << endl;
                    }*/
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strOut += str[i] + to_string(count);
            }
        }
        return strOut;
    }

    int main()
    {
        str = "aabcccccaaa";
        //str.size ~= 11000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            str += str;
        commpres2(str); //107ms //30,32% CPU
        commpres3(str); //147ms //42,58% CPU
    }
```

Now I used release mode and this CPU profiler. So my question is:
Really? Going one thru string to count length takes longer time, than move this string a couple of times inside memory?

Comment: Isnt it a bit too much 7000000 byte for test case? Your test requires just 200 byte memory. Try to reduce it your reserve or increase your for loop iteration for fit that memory.

Comment: Are you running these tests on debug build by any chance?

Comment: Are you compiling your code with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Those running times seem way too much. I've just run your code and it completed in an instant, with `commpres3` being faster than `commpres2`. It would be nice to know how did you measured the running times and whether you ran it in debug or release mode.

Comment: I run this code on debug mode and with optimizations enabled. I measured the time, form breakpoint to breakpoint in Visual Studio. In 'commpres2', reallocation occur a dozen times. Even one relocation must move millions of variables, it doesn't take time?

Comment: @wojtek: Never profile in debug mode. Even with optimizations enabled, you're likely to get the debug memory allocator.

Comment: It does take time, but it's much faster than you think. I recommend you to switch to **Release configuration** in Visual Studio and try the Performance Profiler tool (`Debug menu > Performance Profiler...`). Check the `CPU Usage` box and start the profiling, the `Total CPU` column is the one you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro in this concept but using "i < str.length()" in for loop every time calls a function and gets its value and then compares it to "i" and this takes more time to process your loop.

so to prevent that, in your "compress3" function instead of calling "str.length() everytime you need it, just store it in an Integer like " int len = str.length(); " and in your loop use "i < len" instead of "i < str.length()".

your code should be like this:

```
string commpres3(string str)
{
    string strOut;
    strOut.reserve(7000000);
    int count = 0;
    //int adress = 0;
    int len = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        ++count;
        if (i < len - 1)
        {
            if (str[i + 1] != str[i])
            {
                strOut += str[i];
                strOut += to_string(count);
                /*if (adress != (int)&strOut[0])
                {
                    adress = (int)&strOut[0];
                    cout << adress << endl;
                }*/
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strOut += str[i] + to_string(count);
        }
    }
    return strOut;
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, it would speed up the program a bit. However, in both functions it is used equally, so this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: @wojtek you are right, the buffer you used takes a lot of time, but if you need more fast processing function, you should optimize as much as you can and do not waste cpu clocks.

Comment: In optimized code, `str.length()` is very likely inlined and no longer a function call. Further optimization is likely to spot the fact that the inlined function is simply accessing a data member, and see that the data member is not modified elsewhere. This can then allow a further optimization called hoisting, where the data member is read into a register once (if enough registers are available). This is in fact pretty much _expected_ for modern compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that reducing the number of allocations increases performance is a valid one. To reason about any performance gain we need to see how many allocations `commpres3` saves compared to `commpres2`.

We can use [`strOut.capacity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity) to check the allocated number of bytes. When the capacity increases an allocation (or reallocation) has occurred:

```
// Counting number of allocations of compress 2
string commpres2(string str)
{
    string strOut;
    string::size_type capacity = strOut.capacity();
    int allocations = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (...) {
        // your loop body

        if (capacity < strOut.capacity()) {
            capacity = strOut.capacity();
            ++allocations;
        }
    }

    std::cout << allocations << std::endl;
    return ...;
}
```

Using this code I get a result of only 19 allocations! This can happend due to the (re)allocation strategy of `std::string`. On my machine `std::string` doubles it's memory each time it needs more. Which makes 19 allocations enough to hold the entire result string.

With `compress3` only saving 19 allocations we can see how a performance increase of 7 of milliseconds is reasonable.

Comment: But if I reallocate string (It contains about 6000000 chars) once. It has to move 6000000 chars, it doesn't take time?

Comment: It does take time, but not more than a couple of milliseconds on my machine. You can create a small program to check how much time it takes to reallocate a 6000000 character string.